# How to keep tag at tip of branch?

Tags: mercurial

Let's say I have a changeset I've tagged as "stable". Now I update to "stable" and then start writing my new feature, committing along the way. It's not ready yet, so I don't want to merge it back into stable at this point, but I need to go fix an urgent bug on another branch.

I update to the branch, fix the bug, and commit my changes. Now I want to get back to where I left off, how do I do that?

I can "tag" my feature branch so that I can find it again, but AFAIK tags don't float along my branch as I commit, so it will always be a few revisions behind. This is *good* for "stable" because I don't want that tag to move, but bad for my feature branch.

How do I deal with this?

It just occurred to me that I can `hg up <tag>` and then run `hg up` a second time, and that will bring me to the tip of the branch, no? Seems a bit awkward to run `hg up` twice in a row, but if that's the Mercurial way of doing things, so be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mercurial a bookmark *is* a tag that moves forward whenever you commit.  It sounds like precisely what you want:

```
(df)ry4an-mba:~ ry4an$ hg init smooth_reggae
(df)ry4an-mba:~ ry4an$ cd smooth_reggae/
(df)ry4an-mba:smooth_reggae ry4an$ echo this > AFILE
(df)ry4an-mba:smooth_reggae ry4an$ hg commit -Am first
adding AFILE
(df)ry4an-mba:smooth_reggae ry4an$ hg bookmark stable
(df)ry4an-mba:smooth_reggae ry4an$ hg checkout stable
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
(df)ry4an-mba:smooth_reggae ry4an$ hg summary
parent: 0:fdb32de55e6b tip
 first
branch: default
bookmarks: *stable
commit: (clean)
update: (current)
(df)ry4an-mba:smooth_reggae ry4an$ echo more >> AFILE
(df)ry4an-mba:smooth_reggae ry4an$ hg commit -Am second
(df)ry4an-mba:smooth_reggae ry4an$ hg summary
parent: 1:38cdabce7149 tip
 second
branch: default
bookmarks: *stable
commit: (clean)
update: (current)
(df)ry4an-mba:smooth_reggae ry4an$ hg log -g
changeset:   1:38cdabce7149
bookmark:    stable
tag:         tip
user:        Ry4an Brase <ry4an-hg@ry4an.org>
date:        Wed May 08 20:02:05 2013 -0400
summary:     second

changeset:   0:fdb32de55e6b
user:        Ry4an Brase <ry4an-hg@ry4an.org>
date:        Wed May 08 20:01:31 2013 -0400
summary:     first
```

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I want. From [what I'm reading](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Bookmarks/) it looks like they're private/local-only until you manually push them to the server, which should work well I think. Thank you! `stable` should be a tag I think, and the feature branches should be bookmarks. Otherwise stable will move any time someone starts working on it, no? I want to make sure that it only moves when we're merging changes back into it.

Comment: No, `stable` should not be a tag. `v1.0` should be a tag. Tags are static and shouldn't move. You use tags to identify particular versions, like the version you released as 1.0. The concept of a stable line of development (i.e a "branch") should either be a "named branch" or a "bookmark". Read Steve Losh's [Guide to Branching](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial) to understand what these are.

Comment: @PaulS is right.  Don't plan on moving a 'tag' forward.  Move bookmarks forward.  'stable' should be a branch-like-thing (either a bookmark or a named branch) that you merge stable code in to.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an unnamed branch as your feature branch? If not, your branch surely has a name that you can use in `hg up <branch_name>` to get to its tip.

Comment: It's actually the most reasonable solution. Bookmarks are overkill here, +1

Comment: Assume its unnamed. We have literally thousands of these, they only stay open for a week or two.